Displaying two different layers in the same coordinate systems in QGIS
This looks like an easy solution but, for the life of me, I cannot manage to solve this. I have browsed this website where solutions were provided but unfortunately, none have produced the desired outcome.
I am very novice in QGIS, so any solution provided should be very detailed.
I have downloaded layers that contain information on the type of land cover (source: source of CLC layer). After importing in in QGIS (New Project>Browser>GeoPackage>New Connection>path to file) and then dropping the file in the Layers, I see the layer and its contents. At the bottom right, the CRS is EPSG:25830. In the Properties of the layer (right-click on the layer and click on Properties), I see that the CRS is EPSG:25830. (see the properties of the land cover layer:  and its assigned CRS: )
Now I want to overlay the limits of the municipalities. The SHP file comes from here. To check its coordinate system, I uploaded it to MyGeoCloud. Its reference system is WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator (EPSG:3857). If I import it into a new QGIS project, it displays that value too.
I have tried this:

Import the land cover layer into a new project, then drop the municipalities => failed


Import the municipalities and then the land cover => failed

However, I was under the impression that QGIS (I am using 3.36 Maiden) was able to adjust that.

Reproject the shapefile before importing to the project => failed.
Some answers here suggested reprojecting the layer (I will reproject the municipalities layer). So I did: New Project>Import the limits>Vector>Data Management Tools>Reproject Layer. I chose EPSG: 25830 as the Target CRS. I then export the layer by right-clicking on the layer>Export>Save Features As...> and I choose a name for that file. If I right-click on that exported layer, I see that the CRS of that layer is the one I want:



I create a new project and drop the new shapefile with the CRS of 25830 and the CRS I want is at the bottom-right of QGIS.
I drop the layer of land cover onto that project and it does not match. .
What do I do wrong? Could you list a workflow that would work?
EDIT: steps to download the layers:
Land cover layer:

Go to this link and search ("Buscar")
,
then download the Geopackage file.


SHP file of the municipalities:

Go to this website (or search "municipios ign esri" on Google if the link does not work)
Download as SHP



@babel: will try tomorrow and let you know. Yes, I changed the layer CRS (by reprojecting) because drag and drop did not work. Anyway, I'll try a new project and redo everything to see if that works.

@Babel: that was option 1 in my question. For option 1, I did not change the projection (no assignment, no reprojection), that is why I tried other options. My objective with this is to compute the area of each municipality that is covered by one of the 44 classes available in the Land Cover layer. So I thought of importing both layers by drag and drop and then applying Intersect or Union, but that gave me an error (GEOS is unable to perform the task). The workflow seems simple but I just cannot make it work.

Sure: here's the WMS connection: https://servicios.idee.es/wms-inspire/ocupacion-suelo-historico?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS
and the shapefile is here: https://opendata.esri.es/datasets/ComunidadSIG::municipios-ign/explore?location=34.126543%2C-6.916698%2C5.63
Is this what you need?
My problem is that the behavior of QGIS is not consistent: the drag and drop may work, then I save and reopen and then it no longer matches. I am sure I am missing something.

I do not have access to the computer with QGIS before tonight (European time). Will update when I can. Thanks a lot in advance.
Given what I want to achieve, is it better to use Union or Intersection?

I don't see anything like you show in your updated question. Can you just link to your files on WeTransfer, DropBox, etc?

@Babel: there is no direct link. I have mentioned the WMS connection, but this is as much as I can do. A question: I use a vector map for the land cover. It seems you use a raster. Is this correct? I confirm that I will not touch the CRS.

@Pointdump: for the land cover layer: go to the link I have provided in my edit. Click on "Buscar" on the top left, then "Buscar por listado", then scroll down to the CORINE Land Cover" product, then select "Toda España" in the dropdown on the right and finally press "Buscar" on the right. Within the list of results, choose the one I have provided the screenshot of.

@Babel: I cannot update on this before 7 pm today (in 7 hours). Thank you for your help so far.

@Babel: I did what you suggested: new project, OSM basemap, drag and drop the gpkg file. When I drop the SHP alone, it correctly displays on thop of the basemap. However, when I drag all the sidecar files, I have errors like you. I tried running an intersection between Canarias (the islands West of Africa) and the layer of the municipalities but it failed: Creating spatial index
Calculating intersection
GEOS geoprocessing error: intersection failed.

I believe I no longer have the problem. The problem happened later when I merged two layers. I think I was choosing a CRS. I understand now that that was a mistake. I am immensly grateful for the time you spent on my problem, for the pedagogy you showed but above all else for your patience. I consider the topic closed. If you post an answer mentioning the CRS, I'll accept it. Thank you again.

My workflow now works: 1. OSM basemap, 2. connect to gpckg and shp files, 3. fix geometries (structure and linework) of the three layers (mainland, Canary islands and municipalities), 4. merge mainland and Canary islands witout CRS, 5. Intersection tool with the merged layer, 6. add a field in the attribute table, 7. export as CSV. Done. I will forever remember not to touch the CRS.

The problem seems to be a CRS issue: you probably (wrongly) changed the layer's CRS what you should never do if you're not really 100% sure what you do: see here for details. Whenever a layer does not fit on a basemap, in about 99% it's becaus a wrong CRS definition was assigned to it.
So to solve the problem:

Create a new, empty QGIS project with an OSM basemap and drag and drop your files. They should perfectly allign with the basemap. I always recommend this to see if the data is located in the correct location:


As your files come in two differen CRS (see here and here), for intersecting them, you should reproject them to the same CRS. I would advice to reproject Municipios layer from EPSG:3857 to EPSG:25828 as the other layer. Go to Menu  Processing -> Toolbox -> Reproject Layer.
Alternatively, right click the layer ->  Export ->  save featuers as...  and there, choose the CRS you want to reproject to. This has the advantage that you can also save the file as a Geopackage and avoid the cumbersome handling of Shapefiles.

Another problem with your data appears when you want to Intersect: Feature (522) from “Municipios_IGN” has invalid geometry. Run Fix Geometries to repair them, then Intersection works.


